# No parser for mime type: text/x-java

Tags: java, netbeans

I can't edit the code in my project in java, when i compile the file an Error appear:

> No parser for mime type: text/x-java

When i double click on file, a window without name is opened !! it contains some info about history of the file.
The Netbeans version is 8.1.

[image]

Comment: You're looking at the file's history. There should be a "source" option next to the "history" option just under the tabs. When source mode is selected you can edit your file.

Comment: It seems you don't have a source tab beside `History` tab. Have you already tried to change `compare mode?

Comment: yeah, nothing there .. just to re-order the history (previous to current and vice verca)

Answer (score 1):

I solve it, simply, by deleting version 8.1 and install an older one (7.4).

Answer (score 0):

you have that issue because you are in a version controlled application, you are having conflicts between the file you have and a older/newer modified version..

resolve those differences (merge it) and then you can continue working on the project.

Comment: how? , i don't have any option to do that !